# Log4J2: JsonTemplateLayout timestamp format problem

Tags: java, json, log4j

I jave a log4j timestamp formatting problem, any help will be appreciated.

Using `JsonTemplateLayout` and following xml config, I am trying, with no success, to achieve timestamp formatting like so:
`2020-02-07T13:38:47.098+02:00`(Notice the `:` char at +02:00):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleJSONAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
          <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:log4j2.json"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.my.logger" additivity="false" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleJSONAppender"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

According to the [Timestamp Resolver manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html#event-template-resolver-timestamp) the default format is the one I need,
but the parsed format looks like this:

`2020-02-07T13:38:47.098+0200`. (Notice the missing colon char at +0200)

Following is a snippet from my eventTemplate JSON using default formatting and resulting to the format above.

```
  "timestamp": {
    "$resolver": "timestamp"
  }
```

Using the `ISO8601_OFFSET_DATE_TIME_HHCMM` of [FixedDateFormat.FixedFormat](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/datetime/FixedDateFormat.FixedFormat.html#ISO8601_OFFSET_DATE_TIME_HHCMM) enum also leads to formatting without `:` at +02:00:

```
"timestamp": {
    "$resolver": "timestamp",
    "format": "%d{ISO8601_OFFSET_DATE_TIME_HHCMM}"
  }
```

Strangely, using the format from `ISO8601_OFFSET_DATE_TIME_HHCMM` which is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX`, I get exception:

```
Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout for element JsonTemplateLayout:
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout java.lang.IllegalStateException:
No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout
```

```
"timestamp": {
    "$resolver": "timestamp",
    "pattern": {
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `IllegalStateException` is due to a bug introduced in version 2.15.0 and solved in 2.19.0 (cf. [LOG4J2-3614](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3614)). Upgrade to version 2.20.0 to get rid of it]

Log4j2 uses multiple date formatters: Apache Commons' [`FastDateFormat`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html), Log4j's [`FixedDateFormat`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/datetime/FixedDateFormat.html) (an optimalized version of the first one) and Java's [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

The default JSON Template Layout is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ`, where the time zone part is interpreted as:

- sign + 2 digits + colon + 2 digits by `FastDateFormat`
- sign + 4 digits by `DateTimeFormatter`.

Due to some changes in version 2.15.0 the semantics of the pattern switched from `FastDateFormat` to `DateTimeFormatter`. I have reported it as [Github issue #1420](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1420).

To maintain the previous behavior you need to use:

```json
"timestamp": {
    "$resolver": "timestamp",
    "pattern": {
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx"
    }
}
```

An `XXX` pattern would output `Z` instead of `+00:00`.